# \shortstack in table throwing Compile Error

Tags: tables, errors, compiling, multirow, shortstack

I am trying to put some cell text such as "Measurement type" and "Event labels" into multirow cells of two lines, where the aforementioned names would be split into two lines.

```
   \begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{Summary of high-frequency datasets specific for electricity disaggregation}
    \label{tab:datasets}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{llllcllll}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Dataset}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Year}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack{\textbf{Measurement\\type}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Duration}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack{\textbf{ADC\\resolution}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Sampling frequency}} & \textbf{Features} & \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack{\textbf{Event\\labels}}}\\
    &&&&&\textbf{WP}&\textbf{IL}&&\\
    REDD (US) \cite{REDD2011}& 2011 & WP(10), IC, IL(8)  & 3-119D & 24bit & 15kHz & 1/3-1/4Hz & I,V,P & NO\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{table*}
```

Although I found a solution that revolves around the use of \shortstack, it does not work and I get a Compiler Error!

[image: Errors found when using \shortstack]

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a complete code, please?

Comment: Use `\shortstack` inside of `textbf` not the other way around or switch to the `makecell` package or use `m` type columns for automatic linebreaks.

Comment: This is more a guess than an answer, because I can't test at the moment.  I thi\
nk that the `\\ ` in the `\shortstack` can't be inside a brace pair `{..}`.  Tr\
y this: `\shortstack{\textbf{Measurement}\\ \textbf{type}}`.

Comment: Thank you all. As you mentioned, the problem was with the 
    `\textbf{type}`. 

Giving each word its specific
    `\textbf{type}` solved the problem!

Comment: Don't use `\shortstack`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350278/4427. Also the `minipage` with a `center` environment is not the best idea; just use `\centering` inside the `table*` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in @leandriis' comment, you'll have a simpler code which compiles (no  `\multirow`, no `shortstack`) with `makecell`, which allows for line breaks and a common formatting in standard cells, with the`\makecell` and `\thead` commands. I added `caption` to have a decent spacing between caption and table, used the `\small` size and reduced the value of `\tabcolsep` to make the table fit the text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, caption}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{nccmath} 

\begin{document}

 \begin{table*}[t]
 \small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \caption{Summary of high-frequency datasets specific for electricity disaggregation}
    \label{tab:datasets}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llllcllll}
    \toprule
    \thead{Dataset} & \thead{Year} & \thead{ Measurement\\type} & \thead{Duration} & \thead{ADC\\resolution} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Sampling\\ frequency}} & \thead{Features} & \thead{Event\\labels}\\
    \cline{6-7}
    &&&&&\thead{WP}&\thead{IL}&&\\
    REDD (US) \cite{REDD2011}& 2011 & WP(10), IC, IL(8) & 3-119D & 24\,bit & 15\,kHz & $ \mfrac{1}{3} $--$ \mfrac{1}{4} $\,Hz & I,V,P & NO\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]